# Installing beautifulsoup4 returns "requirement already satisfied"

Tags: macos

I ran:

```
sudo pip install beautifulsoup4
```

And got:

> The directory '/Users//Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>   The directory '/Users//Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>   Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.5.3-py2.7.egg

So I used the -H flag and ran:

```
sudo -H pip install beautifulsoup4
```

> Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.5.3-py2.7.egg

So at this point I am not sure if I am good to go or not.